# How to include multiple bibliographies?

Tags: natbib, subdividing

I want to include a separate bibliography for each chapter. The question below was trying to achieve the same thing

[Putting bibliographies at the end of each chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87991/putting-bibliographies-at-the-end-of-each-chapter)

I have been using `natbib` alone but added `chapterbib` after reading the question but it does not seem to make any difference.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test bib 1}
\input{TB1.tex}
\chapter{Test bib 2}
\input{TB2.tex}
\end{document}
```

TB1.tex

```
\citet*{A12} (LRRE) \citet*{XQ11} 

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Introduction}
```

TB2.tex

```
\citet*{NS87} and its extension by \citet*{Sven94}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Ridge}
```

Ridge.bib

```
@article{NS87,
author = {Nelson, C. R. and Siegel, A. F},
title = {Parsimonious Modelling of Yield Curves},
journal = {The Journal of Business},
volume = {60},
issue={4},
year = {1987},
pages={473-489},
}


@misc{Sven94,
Author = {Svensson, L.E.O},
Title = {Estimating and Interpreting Forward Interest Rates: Sweden 1992-1994},
howpublished={IMF Working Paper},
note = {WP/94/114},         
Year = {1994},
pages={1-49} }
```

Introduction.bib

```
@article{XQ11,
author = {Gao, F and Liu, XQ.},
title = {Linearized Ridge Regression Estimator Under the Mean Square Error Criterion in a Linear Regression Model},
journal = {Communications in Statistics-Simulation and Computation},
volume = {40},
year = {2011},
pages={1434-1443},
 }


@misc{A12,
Author = {Anneart, J. and Claes, A.G.P.,and De Ceuster, M.J.K. and Zhang, H.},
Title = {Estimating the Yield Curve Using the Nelson-Siegel Model: A Ridge Resgression Appoach},
howpublished={International Review of Economics and Finance, Forthcoming},         
Year = {2012},
}
```

Comment: People can't tell what is going on without seeing your calls to the bibliography commands. Most of your preamble is irrelevant and shouldn't be in your MWE. But we need to see e.g. `\bibliography{}` and the bibliography style commands for a sample included file. You should include a sample from your `.bib` file, too, so that people can compile your example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Aside from being unnecessary for the MWE, your preamble really could benefit from being tidied up as you would find it easier to keep track of what is going on. I already commented this preamble in another question, so I won't repeat the details here but just highlight that it really does help with keeping clear about what is happening.

Comment: OK the MWE now replicates the same error! The same bibliography is repeated. Sorry for not doing this first time round!

Comment: I know this could be off-topic. But I think I need to share my experience here. After adding `chapterbib`, all my citations turn to `?`s and I am sure I have separate bbl files generated. After hours' googling, I added the `natbib` package (according to this question) and my citations came back. I don't know the reason, but hope this could help someone.

Answer (score 2):

First, a minor issue:

- There is an error in one of your bib entries. In `A12`, you need

  Author = {Anneart, J. and Claes, A.G.P. and De Ceuster, M.J.K. and Zhang, H.},

You have an extra comma which causes errors.

Second, you really need to read the documentation for `chapterbib`. By default `chapterbib` expects you to `\include` files. If for some reason you can't do this, it offers alternatives but `\include` is going to be the most straightforward solution.

Third, don't include the `.tex` suffix in the file names of the chapters as `chapterbib` cannot cope with them and it is generally better not to do so anyway.

So, you should end up with something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test bib 1}
\include{TB1}
\chapter{Test bib 2}
\include{TB2}
\end{document}
```

which yields two bibliographies:

[image: biblio 1]

and

[image: biblio 2]

Comment: Thanks so much!!! One problem though when I run the code only the first set of references and bibliography show, it seems that it can not find Ridge?

Comment: Did you run `pdflatex` followed by `bibtex TB1.aux` then `bibtex TB2.aux` then `pdflatex` twice more?

Comment: I think the aux files might have been playing up I deleted them started over with the process above and it works!!!