# Multiple Bibliographies one for each Chapter with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I've been strugging all day to include multiple bibligraphies (one for each chapter) in my report, I first tried using chapterbib but that isn't working!:

[How to include multiple bibliographies?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202216/how-to-include-multiple-bibliographies)

So I want to look at alternative as I simply must get this to work!!!!

I have tried doing something similar with biblatex, but it falls short in a few key ways:

3.) I'd like to be able to use separate .bib files for each chapter. Still can't figure out how to do this!

One step forward I can now load multiple bib files in the preamble:
The refsections then take whichever references that are cited in their section from both bibs and display them at the \printbibliography in their section
The \printbibliography at the end of the document displays both .bib files in their entirety.

But what I want is to be able to print the entire contents of just one of the bib files at the end of each chapter?

1.) Currently it just prints a bibliography of all the citations made in the report thus producing the same bibliography three times, at the very least it should only show the references that were cited in the current chapter.

OK I have solved Q1 (at least partially) I put a refsection around each chapter. I then ran bibtex on the corresponding aux files. It now prints a separate bibliography for each chapter containing references for all citations in that chapter. However it no longer prints the big bibliography at the end.

2.) It only shows cited references in the bibliography, I want to show all references whether they were cited or not. OK this is solved by adding \nocite{*} to the document.

Can all this be achieved with biblatex?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Introduction.bib}
\addbibresource{Ridge.bib}    
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\chapter{Test bib 1}
\begin{refsection}
\input{TB1.tex}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\chapter{Test bib 2}
\begin{refsection}    
\input{TB2.tex}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

TB1.tex:

```
  \cite{A12} (LRRE) \cite{XQ11}
```

TB2.tex

```
  \cite{NS87} and its extension by \cite{Sven94}
```

Introduction.bib

```
@article{XQ11,
author = {Gao, F and Liu, XQ.},
title = {Linearized Ridge Regression Estimator Under the Mean Square Error Criterion in a Linear Regression Model},
journal = {Communications in Statistics-Simulation and Computation},
volume = {40},
year = {2011},
pages={1434-1443},
}


@misc{A12,
Author = {Anneart, J. and Claes, A.G.P.,and De Ceuster, M.J.K. and Zhang, H.},
Title = {Estimating the Yield Curve Using the Nelson-Siegel Model: A Ridge Resgression Appoach},
howpublished={International Review of Economics and Finance, Forthcoming},         
Year = {2012},
}

@article{NS87,
author = {Nelson, C. R. and Siegel, A. F},
title = {Parsimonious Modelling of Yield Curves},
journal = {The Journal of Business},
volume = {60},
issue={4},
year = {1987},
pages={473-489},
}

@misc{Sven94,
Author = {Svensson, L.E.O},
Title = {Estimating and Interpreting Forward Interest Rates: Sweden 1992-1994},
howpublished={IMF Working Paper},
note = {WP/94/114},         
Year = {1994},
pages={1-49} }


@article{CP01,
Author = {Cairns, A.J.G. and Pritchard, D.J.},
Title = {Stability of Descriptive Models for the Term Structure of Interest Rates with Applications to German Market Data},
journal = {British Actuarial Journal},
volume = {7},
year = {2001},
pages={467-507}}
```

Comment: Do you want to use `\nocite{*}` in the chapter and print only the cites in a .bib file?.For this not load the .bib file in the preamble, you can load the .bib in the `refsection` using `\begin{refsection}[introduction.bib]<content>\end{refsection}`. The global .bib can be load using  `\addglobalbib{resourse}` in the preamble.

Comment: `biblatex` allows to create lists of references divided according with keywords you use, but I'm not sure yet how to achieve exactly what you want. In the backend you can use `biber`, it allows you to manage the references in a more efficient way.

Comment: Please correct `A12`. For details see my answer to your question about how to do this with `chapterbib`!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this does what you want (having just reread your question).

If you plan to include a global bibliography, you need to use `refsegment` rather than `refsection`, I think, to ensure unique labels.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname1.bib}
@article{XQ11,
author = {Gao, F and Liu, XQ.},
title = {Linearized Ridge Regression Estimator Under the Mean Square Error Criterion in a Linear Regression Model},
journal = {Communications in Statistics-Simulation and Computation},
volume = {40},
year = {2011},
pages={1434-1443}}

@misc{A12,
Author = {Anneart, J. and Claes, A.G.P. and De Ceuster, M.J.K. and Zhang, H.},
Title = {Estimating the Yield Curve Using the Nelson-Siegel Model: A Ridge Resgression Appoach},
howpublished={International Review of Economics and Finance, Forthcoming},
Year = {2012}}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname2.bib}
@article{NS87,
author = {Nelson, C. R. and Siegel, A. F},
title = {Parsimonious Modelling of Yield Curves},
journal = {The Journal of Business},
volume = {60},
issue={4},
year = {1987},
pages={473-489}}

@misc{Sven94,
Author = {Svensson, L.E.O},
Title = {Estimating and Interpreting Forward Interest Rates: Sweden 1992-1994},
howpublished={IMF Working Paper},
note = {WP/94/114},
Year = {1994},
pages={1-49}}


@article{CP01,
Author = {Cairns, A.J.G. and Pritchard, D.J.},
Title = {Stability of Descriptive Models for the Term Structure of Interest Rates with Applications to German Market Data},
journal = {British Actuarial Journal},
volume = {7},
year = {2001},
pages={467-507}}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[backend=biber, refsegment=chapter, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource[label=intro]{\jobname1.bib}
\addbibresource[label=ridge]{\jobname2.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test bib 1}
\cite{A12} (LRRE) \cite{XQ11}
\printbibliography[segment=1,heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Test bib 2}
\cite{NS87} and its extension by \cite{Sven94}
\printbibliography[segment=2,heading=subbibliography]

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: multiple bibliographies with unique labels for a global list]

Comment: Using your code, the bibliography is not visualised anywhere... Do I have to compile in some special way?

Comment: @SeF Only the usual. Did you forget to run biber? Or did you run bibtex instead? This wants biber as the backend.

Comment: Indeed, I was miss the biber part. Running > pdflatex document.tex > biber document, pdflatex> document.tex made it working. Thanks!

Comment: @cfr, if I am not going to insert a global one, how to reset the numbering to have all bibliography starting from 1?

Comment: In most cases one can use `segment=\the\value{refsegment}` instead of a explicit `segment=1` etc. It is longer, but does not require that one keep track of the segment numbers.

Comment: I'm trying to use this code in my document, however I cannot get it to work. I would like to use a single, separate .bib file, sperate chapter .tex and a main.txt running from a .cls. This is the code I am working with on the main.tex:

\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=numeric,natbib=true,sorting=none,refsegment=chapter,defernumbers=true]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{example.bib} 

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

and chapter1.tex as printed:
\printbibliography[segment=1,heading=subbibliography]
Empty bib err

Comment: Nevermind - I read the above comment and added '\the\value{refsegment}' to the segment = and now it works. Thanks!