# Show different bibliography for each chapter with \nocite{*}

Tags: natbib

I'm working on combining 3 separate Tex files into a single article document with consistent formatting for the whole. The issue is that the bibliography from the first section keeps repeating for each section. Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document} 

text for chapter 1 

\pagebreak

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{chapter_1}
\nocite{*} 

\pagebreak

text for chatper 2 

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{chapter_2}
\nocite{*} 

\pagebreak

text for chatper 3 

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{chapter_3}
\nocite{*} 

\end{document}
```

each chapter is has its own bib file and I don't use the in text citation commands (hence the \nocite{*} ). Is there any way I can get latex to just show a new reference list every time I include one? I'd appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: An article have no chapters. If your real documentclass have chapters see `chapterbib` package documentation and my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202281/multiple-bibliographies-one-for-each-chapter-with-biblatex (Haven't flag yet until your answer that this link solves your problem, because the solution there doesn't include `\nocite{*}` and I suppose you have to split into chapters and `filecontents` way will probably not work [not tested])

Answer (score 3):

A good idea is to split your code into chapters:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document} 

\include{Chap1}
\include{Chap2}

\end{document}
```

Chapter1.tex:

```
\chapter{test chap 1}

\lipsum[1-5]
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Chap1}
```

Chap1.bib:

```
@article{entry1chap1,
title={Bibentry1 title},
author={none},
year={2017}
}
@article{entry2chap1,
title={Bibentry2 title},
author={none},
year={2016}
}
```

Chapter2.tex:

```
\chapter{test chap 2}

\lipsum[1-5]
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Chap2}
```

Chap2.bib:

```
@article{entry1chap2,
title={Bibentry3 title},
author={none},
year={2017}
}
@article{entry2chap2,
title={Bibentry4 title},
author={none},
year={2016}
}
```

Compilation:

1. `pdflatex` on main.tex
2. `bibtex` on each Chapter.tex
3. Double `pdflatex` on `main.tex`