# independent bibliographies in one document

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, subdividing

I am working on a document where each abstract has its own bibliography. How can I put references for each contribution independently of the others? I am currently using natbib, but if you guys have some better ideas, I'm all ears!

Comment: Maybe have a look at the answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87991/putting-bibliographies-at-the-end-of-each-chapter?

Comment: Thanks. Although, here I would like to print the relevant bibliography _without_ creating sections. Do you know any resource I can refer to? I checked the biblatex documentation, but it's somewhat obscure to me...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `biblatex` there is the possibility to use the `refsection` environment:

```
\begin{refsection}

    you text with \cite{whatever}
    \printbibliography

\end{refsection}
```

With this `\printbibliography` will only print the items cited within this environment.